# How Aurora postgres serverless v2 manage read consistency?

Tags: postgresql, aws-aurora

Vanilla Postgres relies on the Database Master to enforce read consistency by applying uncheckpointed TXs or 'hiding' the result of transactions committed after a query has started.  Does this logic get offloaded to the Aurora storage subsystem with servicerless v2?  If not, any reason why it could not be?

Answer (score 0):

There's no "Database Master" that "hides the result of transactions", or anything like that. Instead, the backend processes reading data ignore the tuples modified after the respective transactions had begun.

AWS Aurora has its own storage access mechanism, but there's no reason to believe it uses a different concurrency model (which cannot be "offloaded to the Aurora storage subsystem", because the latter does not know anything about transactions, or perhaps even tuples).